# mysqli_query inputs via variable

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I'm trying to add information to a MySQL table using the following PHP code. (The input the name and text from an HTML5 basic web form.) Probably a syntax issue?

```
<?php
include "dbinfo.php"; //contains mysqli_connect information (the $mysqli variable)
//inputs
$name = $_GET["name"];
$text = $_GET["text"];

$sqlqr = 'INSERT INTO `ncool`.`coolbits_table` (`name`, `text`, `date`) VALUES ("$name", "$text", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);'; //the query. I'm pretty sure that the problem is a syntax one, and is here somewhere.

mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlqr); //function where the magic happens.
?>
```

No error is thrown. A blank screen results, and a row with "$name" and "$text" is added to the MySQL table.

Comment: Warning! Your code is dangerously vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Read up on how to escape your SQL variables, preferably using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Based on the posted code, an inserted row and a blank screen is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: What does mysqli_error() return?

Comment: @EdGibbs Yes,but it is the variable name (literally $name) that's added, not its value.

Comment: @Jocelyn mysqli_error() doesn't return anything (assuming I'm using it correctly).

Comment: @NoahCoolidge - sorry, I read it too fast and didn't realize you meant "literally $name". Hope I didn't come off as snarky; that definitely wasn't my intent. The single quotes you have around your query string are part of your problem: they won't substitute the variable values as Uby and others are pointing out. You'll get literally `$name` instead of the-value-of-name. This becomes moot when you use mysqli prepared statements, so have a try at those. They're not as scary as they sound, they're a lot safer, and there are plenty of nice tutorials on how to use them.

Comment: @nocoolsoft Check my revised answer. Should be no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how your code should look (with added SQL Injection protection):**

```
<?php
include "dbinfo.php"; //contains mysqli_connect information (the $mysqli variable)
//inputs
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['text']);

$sqlqr = "INSERT INTO `ncool`.`coolbits_table` (`name`, `text`, `date`) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $text . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlqr); //function where the magic happens.
?>
```

Take a look at what I've done. Firstly I've escaped the user input you're retrieving into the `$name` and `$text` variables (this is pretty much a must for security reasons) and as others have suggested you should preferably be using prepared statements.

The problem is that you weren't surrounding string values with single quotes ('), which is a requirement of the SQL syntax.

I hope this helps to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to give a few errors (on the $sqlqr line and with the inputs) but I'm pretty sure that I know what's going on there and will fix it.

Comment: @EM-Creations You need to fix the single and double quotes.

Comment: The procedural `mysqli_real_escape_string()` takes two parameters: the string to escape and also the $link variable. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: will it still work if I use  VALUES ('$name ', ' $text ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) instead of  VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $text . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ? If yes, then can you please explain why ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all: you should use mysqli prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. **It is not safe** to use user input within a query without proper escaping. Prepared statements are useful to prevent this.

Second: you should learn how string quoting works in PHP, **single quoted strings and double quoted strings are different**

I would recommend to read the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) about string quoting.

Comment: will take a look and read up on it. I thought that I'd read it thoroughly enough, but I guess I need to look it over some more.