# mysql table update gives no result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I made a html form that updates some fields in my table in mySQL DB the for after succeful updates should direct me to success page otherwise give error msg. indicating the error

I use form validation but so far nothing happens to the fields in my table it only directs me to a blank page

here is the form code :

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="http://localhost/wordpress/orgupdate.php" method="post" name="myForm">
        Name <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
        Telephone <input id="telephone" type="text" name="telephone" />
        Fax <input id="fax" type="text" name="fax" />
        Web address <input id="webaddress" type="text" name="webaddress" />
        State <input id="state" type="text" name="state" />
        Address <input id="address" type="text" name="address" />
        <input type="submit"  name= "submit" value="update" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    /* JS validation code here */

    function validateForm()
    {
        /* Validating name field */
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        /* Validating email field */
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["telephone"].value;

        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("telephone must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
// ]]>
</script>
```

and this is my php file :

```
<?php 
//establish connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xxxx","android_app"); 
//on connection failure, throw an error
if(!$con) {  
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
}

//get the form elements and store them in variables
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$telephone=$_POST['telephone']; 
$fax=$_POST['fax']; 
$webaddress=$_POST['webaddress']; 
$state=$_POST['state']; 
$address=$_POST['address'];

$query= update  islamic_organisation SET (Telephone ='$telephone', Fax ='$fax', WebAddress ='$webaddress', state ='$state', Address ='$address' WHERE  Name  ='$name');

//Redirects to the specified page
header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=857");
?>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Your update query is wrong, and the function name is suspicious

Comment: First, how do you not get a parse error on `$query = update...`, it needs to be quoted properly.  Secondly, you never execute your query, only assign it to a variable.

Comment: I beg you, read about SQL injections before pushing this code to production, even internal. :)

Comment: @spacediver but this is not going for industrial it's just my final year project..I bet it's not worthy doing the anti-SQL injection,right?coz this might take sometime which I need to do some higher priority works.....but thanks for the hint dude ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$query= "update  islamic_organisation SET Telephone ='$telephone', Fax ='$fax', WebAddress ='$webaddress', state ='$state', Address ='$address' WHERE  Name  ='$name'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

EDIT 1:

```
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($con));
```

Comment: I tried your query still nothing updated !!!

Comment: @user2309720, if no error returns, then your query have no problem. you can check if some rows updated with `mysqli_affected_rows($con)`, if zero record updated, then your query did not find any record with your `where` condition you specified

Comment: I looked into the table and all the fields are intact, no changes

Comment: okay now it does the update but in such a weird way when I fill up the form I have to give one space after the value in name field even though I jut put some value directly into name field in the table with no space!!!!!!! I wonder!!!!

Comment: @user2309720,perhaps you inserted extra space into column `name` in the table

Answer (score 2):

Few points:

1. If you get blank page it usually means there is an error somewhere but is not showing because you have turned off debugging.

   You turn debug on by going to wp-config.php and set it to true:

   ```
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   ```
2. Your `$query= update` line is really strange. As Jon mentioned in the
   comments, you should get an error there.
3. When naming your fields for the forms in WordPress, avoid using
   generic words like "name","city" and use more unique ones.

**UPDATE: (Important)**

I just noticed you are putting raw user input into the SQL statements. You should protect your queries against **SQL Injections**.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643285/850010) to a question about `mysqli_query` that shows you how to do that.

Comment: I have turned debug on nothing happened
I have updated my query following Amir's script also no fields updated

Comment: In http://localhost/wordpress/orgupdate.php add some echo "hello"; line to test if the page even starts executing there.

Comment: now it's updating and directing me to the success page...but I just wonder if I need to make it bit professional if user key in invalid name it will show error rather than the success page how can I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer which you MUST address. Regarding invalid name just test if UPDATE failed and then you can have different ways to deal with it. I would redirect back to the form and maybe even add some query string in the URL like ?status=failed and then form would check for it and display some sort of message "name not found". So you would test for "if ($_GET['status']=='failed')...