# Select equal values from column with inner join (sql)

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to SQL, so please dont go too hard on me :(

I have got two tables - "cart" and "orders". In the "cart" table are all the things a random user has ordered - in this case these few rows (with the column names above):

```
session_id  - product_id - product - product_name - price - quantity

1 - 1 - Table - Something - 10.00 - 1  

1 - 2 - Chair - SomethingNew - 20.00 - 1

2 - 2 - Chair - SomethingNew - 20.00 - 1
```

I want to write a statement that selects all the orders with the same session_id - in this case the number 1 - and copy it into the "orders" table, because all the items with the same session id should be labeled as one big order - but i don't want to hard code it (with select and session_id=1 for instance)...
This is what i have got so far for my selection:

I tried using a inner/self join, so that i can check if the values are the same

```
SELECT * from cart JOIN cart AS cartB
WHERE cart.session_id = cartB.session_id
GROUP BY cart.session_id;
```

But this currently gives me the following rows as solution:

```
session_id  - product_id - product - product_name - price - quantity

1 - 1 - Table - Something - 10.00 - 1  

2 - 2 - Chair - SomethingNew - 20.00 - 1
```

Instead of (what i would have wanted):

```
session_id  - product_id - product - product_name - price - quantity

1 - 1 - Table - Something - 10.00 - 1  

1 - 2 - Chair - SomethingNew - 20.00 - 1
```

EDIT: I know, the 2nd and 3rd rows are pretty similar. But thats exactly why the session id is very important in this case, and why i'd like to make it work.

What am i doing wrong? Is the inner join even needed? I am really having some problems with the statment since i am a huge beginner here.. but my code would make sense to me.. :( 
Big thanks to everybody who takes his time to read this (and maybe even help)!

Comment: Your first table structure has 6 columns, but your data has 5. Then your current result vs expected is exactly the same? Are you sure you pasted the correct code?

Comment: Oh wait i forgot one column here you are right, 1sec i'll edit, stupid copy paste >.> But my expected and current result arent the same. One has two times session id "1" - the other one has session ids "1" and "2".

Comment: You just simply need a where cart.session_id=1 without any joins.

Comment: But like i said in my text: i do NOT want to hard code it this way. Because it should work even when there are other session_id numbers ...

Comment: Have you tried removing the `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: I don't see the business logic you are trying to implement. If it is moving the items a guy ordered, from cart to orders, then you have to get the IDs of the approved orders from outside SQL and pass them TO SQL -- SQL can't know what happened in your webshop unless you tell it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I see here 2 options:

Either your PROGRAM passes to SQL the session IDs for orders that you want to copy to orders table, -- which would be normal in any webshop.

In which case you have to get the correct `session_id=` from your program and [pass it to your SQL query as a parameter, eg. in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642910/mysqli-query-inputs-via-variable).

Or you want to copy ALL session_id'd cart contents into orders. In which case it is even simpler, without any WHERE: `INSERT INTO order SELECT * FROM cart;`

If you want something else, you should specify, how it is determined WHICH session_id's need to be copied from cart to orders.

UPD. And you are right, the JOIN in your example doesn't appear to do anything useful.

Comment: I did not downvote yours, i would love to know why people downvotet my initial question as well..

Comment: No worries. I don't know why you were downvoted without a comment. Possibly because somebody couldn't understand what you wanted to achieve.